# Zero-that clause (noun clause with that)

Tags: technical-writing, structure, grammar

After omitting "that" from a that-clause, is the clause still dependent? 
Or, does doing this turn it into an independent clause?

For example:

- Before: "I suggested that she not go there."
- After: "I suggested she not go there."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is still a dependent clause.  Nothing has transformed its structure.